# How can I map the primary domain for subsite as subdirectory for another domain?

Tags: multisite, domain

I'm sorry if the title is a little confusing, I couldn't think of a more concise wording.

I am using Multisite with GoDaddy hosting and just mapped a subsite to www.subsite1.com using the Wordpress MU Domain Mapping plugin. I have a second subsite related to the first one that needed to be its own subsite for various reasons. I would like this site to be accessible at www.subsite1.com/subsite2.

Or can I set it up as a subdomain? subsite2.subsite1.com?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to achieve:

- installdomain.com
- sub.installdomain.com
- sub.installdomain.com/sub2

OR

- installdomain.com
- installdomain.com/sub/
- installdomain.com/sub/sub2

You're describing a **Network of Networks**.

*InstallDomain* is a network (aka multisite), and has a site named *Sub*.
The site *Sub* is also a network.
The *Sub* network has a site named *Sub2*.

There are a lot of things to take into consideration, but it is definitely doable. However, I DO NOT think you can do a subdirectory second-layer network with subdomains; i.e.:

- installdomain.com
- installdomain.com/sub/
- sub2.installdomain.com/sub/

I'll try to add enough relevant links to get you in the right direction.
A good (a decently recent) introduction:

[WPMU DEV article on *Create a Network of Networks* from **Dec 2016**](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/network-of-multisite-networks/?utm_expid=3606929-108.O6f5ypXuTg-XPCV9sY1yrw.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

---

This repo is a good way to bounce through some code. Especially the opening cookie related stuff that's often overlooked.

[Github Repo for Wp_Multi_Network, last updated **May 2017**](https://github.com/stuttter/wp-multi-network)

---

Another angle on it:

[Creating Nested SubFolders with Sunrise.php from **Oct 2013**](https://paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multisite-nested-paths)

---

In case you prefer the talk-in-front-of-a-whiteboard option:

[A 2014 WordCamp Chicago Talk on Multi-Site and Multi-Network by John James Jacoby: 50+mins](https://wordpress.tv/2014/07/26/john-james-jacoby-multisite-and-multi-network/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the primary site is www.example.com . You should be able to use the MU Domain Mapping plugin on www.example.com/site2 site to point that subsite to www.mydomain.com .

Comment: The site I want to map is actually at www.primaryinstall.com/subsite2. I want to move it so it is an extention of www.subsite1.com